# How can I prevent a RadioButton from being checked when the Form loads?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I can't seem to prevent my form from checking one of the **Radio Buttons** in my `Group Box`:

[image]

As shown in the designer, no **Radio Buttons** are checked there.

Below is just about all of the code for this simple form. Nothing calls for a **Radio Buttons** to be checked here or in the form's designer.

**Q:** Is there a way to prevent any **Radio Button** from being checked when the form loads?

```
public ValueTypeSelector() {
  InitializeComponent();
  radioButton1.Checked = false;
  radioButton2.Checked = false;
  radioButton3.Checked = false;
  radioButton4.Checked = false;
  radioButton5.Checked = false;
  radioButton6.Checked = false;
  button1.Enabled = false;
  button1.Click += clickEvent;
  button2.Click += clickEvent;
  radioButton1.Click += clickEvent;
  radioButton2.Click += clickEvent;
  radioButton3.Click += clickEvent;
  radioButton4.Click += clickEvent;
  radioButton5.Click += clickEvent;
  radioButton6.Click += clickEvent;
}

void OnShow(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  foreach (RadioButton rad in Controls) {
    if (rad.Checked) {
      Console.WriteLine("WTF?");
    }
  }
}

void clickEvent(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  RadioButton rad = sender as RadioButton;
  if (rad != null) {
    if (rad.Checked) {
      if (rad == radioButton1) {
        DataType = TableDataType.Boolean; // <= HERE IS THE PROBLEM! FIRES ON FORM LOAD
      } else if (rad == radioButton2) {
        DataType = TableDataType.Character;
      } else if (rad == radioButton3) {
        DataType = TableDataType.DateTime;
      } else if (rad == radioButton4) {
        DataType = TableDataType.Decimal;
      } else if (rad == radioButton5) {
        DataType = TableDataType.Integer;
      } else if (rad == radioButton6) {
        DataType = TableDataType.String;
      } else {
        return;
      }
      button1.Enabled = true;
    }
  } else if (sender == button1) {
    DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    Close();
  } else if (sender == button2) {
    DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
    Close();
  }
}
```

**UPDATE:** The problem is that `radioButton1` gets checked when the form is shown:

```
      if (rad == radioButton1) {
        DataType = TableDataType.Boolean; // <= HERE IS THE PROBLEM! FIRES ON FORM LOAD
      } else if (rad == radioButton2) {
```

Comment: add some radio button, and make it invisible:)

Comment: LOL. I'd rather take control of my code!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Make sure your radiobuttons are NOT the first tabindex = 0 controls.  Make the OK button tabindex=0, followed by the radiobuttons.

Comment: Ah-ha! I knew it had to be something simple like that! Thanks.

Comment: @jp2code or turn the AutoCheck properties of the radiobuttons to false in the designer, and then turn them to true in the constructor.  That seemed to work, too.

Comment: There's even simpler solution to it. Check the comment in my answer area.

Comment: I just want to say that this is a very stupid bug. Thanks!

Comment: @jp2codeThis absolutely works, but it does not have to be done in the designer. It can also be done programmatically: radioButton1.AutoCheck = false;

Answer (score 15):

In the design mode, you'll find the AutoCheck property set to true. Just turn it to false. It won't be checked untill you select it manually during the runtime.

Comment: I am trying to edit my content, but it won't let me. Keeping the **AutoDrop** and **AutoCheck** to true would do what you want.

Comment: I suppose that would work. By doing so, I'd have to explicitly check the `Radio Button` in code in the `clickEvent` handler, right?

Comment: Yes. You can check the Radio Button through code or through the UI. You can handle the change in CheckedChanged event.

Comment: Thanks! I may have used LarsTech's response as the answer, but I've given you 4 distinct upvotes in this thread.

Comment: That's not a problem. I am glad that I could help.

Answer (score 4):

Set `TabStop=False` in properties.

Answer (score 1):

Set the checked state to false after form load. Put this in Shown event and see if it working.

Comment: That's a brute force technique I was trying to avoid. LarsTech's original answer was the fastest to do what I needed, though SaravananArumugam's was probably more correct from the Coder's view.

Answer (score 1):

I think this might actually be a bug in VS. I'm using 2010 SP1 but OP doesn't mention which version they're using.

Had the same phantomness happening in one of my apps.

Changed Autochecked for the two radio buttons to False, built the app. The affected buttons were now not selected, but other ones previously unaffected were now selected.

Went back into code and turned autocheck to true on the original buttons, and then toggled from true to false and back again on the newly affected buttons. Re ran and the app was fine; no buttons selected.

When I first checked the tabIndexes for the original radio buttons they were set to tabIndex 0; which I changed, so that could also be part of the mix.

Comment: I didn't mention it, but it does have the `visual-studio-2010` tag. The moderators on here scold people for posting questions with tags in the subject. Silly StackOverflow rules, I think.